# Decompiled DSDT table, looking for fan values, can't locate. table inside

Tags: fan, cpu-usage, dsdt

I have the suspicion that my laptop doesn't set it's fan speed to 100% even when the CPU is hot. This is because I can barely hear the fan when the CPU is > 95 degrees or so.

So i'm trying to check if this is true in the DSDT table, but I can't find where the values are.

Here is the table: http://www.mediafire.com/?uhhluaqw03qsl73

If anyone can help me find the value, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe because it's too dirty or dusty, try cleaning it and see if it will change.

Comment: @Davidenko it's a brand new laptop. It is already clean :/

Comment: try going into bios, hit DEL, or F2 on power up, and look for cpu fan settings.

Comment: @Davidenko unfortunately there are no such settings, it's a HP DV7 Laptop, I really hate it how major brands lock down their BIOS's...